# Again, regular expression matching in python

Tags: python, regex

Sorry for the general title. I am looking for a python `re` expression to match following regular expression:

`stringOfAlphaNumeric1 ( stringOfAnyCharacter1 , stringOfAnyCharacter2 , stringOfAnyCharacter3 )`

This expression can be repeated many times separating by white space. For example:

`stringOfAlphaNumeric1 ( stringOfAnyCharacter1 , stringOfAnyCharacter2 , stringOfAnyCharacter3 ) stringOfAlphaNumeric2 ( stringOfAnyCharacter4 , stringOfAnyCharacter5 , stringOfAnyCharacter6 )`

How can I get the following pairs:

```
stringOfAlphaNumeric1 -> stringOfAnyCharacter1
stringOfAlphaNumeric1 -> stringOfAnyCharacter2
stringOfAlphaNumeric1 -> stringOfAnyCharacter3
stringOfAlphaNumeric2 -> stringOfAnyCharacter4
stringOfAlphaNumeric2 -> stringOfAnyCharacter5
stringOfAlphaNumeric2 -> stringOfAnyCharacter6
```

Comment: That is pretty basic regular expression, what did you do that didn't work ?

Comment: What do you mean by the state transitions (e.g. stringOfAlphaNumeric1 -> stringOfAnyCharacter1)? You're not implementing a DFA...

Comment: @mmgp it's not *that* trivial (in a single expression), since matches can generally not overlap and lookbehinds in Python can not be of variable length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

#if its fixed:  [  Key ( Value1 , Value2 , Value3 )  ]
regex = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z0-9]+) \( (.+?) , (.+?) , (.+?) \)')
s = "stringOfAlphaNumeric1 ( stringOfAnyCharacter1 , stringOfAnyCharacter2 , stringOfAnyCharacter3 ) stringOfAlphaNumeric2 ( stringOfAnyCharacter4 , stringOfAnyCharacter5 , stringOfAnyCharacter6 )"

d = dict((i[0], i[1:]) for i in regex.findall(s))
```

d is:

```
{'stringOfAlphaNumeric2': ('stringOfAnyCharacter4', 'stringOfAnyCharacter5', 'stringOfAnyCharacter6'), 
'stringOfAlphaNumeric1': ('stringOfAnyCharacter1', 'stringOfAnyCharacter2', 'stringOfAnyCharacter3')}
```

to get pairs:

```
[(k, i) for k, v in d.items() for i in v]
```

yields:

```
[('stringOfAlphaNumeric2', 'stringOfAnyCharacter4'), 
('stringOfAlphaNumeric2', 'stringOfAnyCharacter5'), 
('stringOfAlphaNumeric2', 'stringOfAnyCharacter6'), 
('stringOfAlphaNumeric1', 'stringOfAnyCharacter1'), 
('stringOfAlphaNumeric1', 'stringOfAnyCharacter2'), 
('stringOfAlphaNumeric1', 'stringOfAnyCharacter3')]
```